# Contains half a tuple

Tags: c#, search, tuples

How can I check if a list contains a tuple partial match?

```cs
var tuples = new List<(int, int)>( new [] { (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2) } );
tuples.Contains((3, _));
```

Comment: You can create the list directly btw: `new List<(int,int)>{(1,1),(1,2),(3,4),(4,2)};`, and you can give the members names `new List<(int X, int Y)>{(1,1),(1,2),(3,4),(4,2)};` and e.g. PMF's suggestion becomes `Any(t=> t.X == 3)`, or you can put the name in the lambda `x.Any(((int X, int Y) t) => t.X == 3);`

Comment: Partial means either Item1 or Item2 match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq:

```cs
var tuples = new List<(int, int)>(new[] { (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2) });
if (tuples.Any(x => x.Item1 == 3))
{
   //....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern matching `is` operator, which is very close to the syntax you had in mind:

```
tuples.Any(x => x is (3, _));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom `Contains` function, but a `.Where` will work just fine:

```
using System.Linq;
[...]

tuples.Where(tup => tup.Item1 == 3);
```